# How to find random documents without aggregate using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am getting the below error when trying to find 8 random records from 200 documents using aggregate. I was on mongodb 3.6 when i first got this issue. With not much help i decided to upgrade my mongodb to 4.2 hoping that it might solve my problem. But today I got this error again. Is there any solution to my problem or is it possible to do random search using find()

```
OperationFailure: $sample stage could not find a non-duplicate document after 100 while using a random cursor. This is likely a sporadic failure, please try again.
```

Below is the command which I use to find random records.

```
reco = db.Products2.aggregate([{'$match': {"MainPage":"Yes"}},{'$sample': {'size': 8}}])
```

Comment: are you using pymongo driver or direct MongoDB query? I did't reproduce this issue on my system.

Comment: @Ashok - I am using pymongo driver